# How to strip white spaces from a string containing HTML content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I could easily strip white space in the left side of a normal string like this:

```
"     Remove whitespace".lstrip #=> "Remove whitespace"
```

But if the string contains HTML I am not able to do it:

```
@html_str = "<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Remove whitespace &nbsp;</p>"
@html_safe_str = @html_str.html_safe #=> "     Remove whitespace"
@html_safe_str.lstrip #=> "<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Remove whitespace</p>"
```

`@html_str.html_safe.lstrip` is not working.

I dont want to remove all the `&nbsp;`s in the string. I want to remove all the `&nbsp;`s immediately after the opening `<p>` tag

Expected result: `"Remove whitespace &nbsp;"`

How is it possible?

Comment: Post expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 4, `strip_tags` has been combined with `gsub`. You can use `gsub` to remove `&nbsp;`s. Then, you need to use `sanitizer` method provided by `ActionView`:

```
@html_str = "<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Remove whitespace &nbsp;</p>"
str = @html_str.gsub(/<p>\s*(&nbsp;\s*)+/, "<p>")
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(str).lstrip # => "Remove whitespace &nbsp;"
```

It will  work for Rails 3 as well as Rails 4.

Comment: gsub(/<p>\s*(&nbsp;\s*)+/, "<p>") worked perfectly! Thanks @RAJ !

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
@html_str = "<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Remove whitespace</p>"

@html_str = @html_str.gsub("&nbsp;", "") => "<p>    Remove whitespace</p>"

@html_str1 = ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(@html_str) => "    Remove whitespace" #if you are doing this at controller level

@html_str1 = strip_tags(@html_str) => "    Remove whitespace"  #if you are doing this at view level

#now at the last 

@html_str2 = @html_str1.strip => "Remove whitespace"
```

Shortly:

```
@html_str = "<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Remove whitespace</p>"

@html_str1 = ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(@html_str.gsub("&nbsp;", "")).strip => "Remove whitespace"
```

Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

If `html_safe` converts `&nbsp;`'s to white spaces, you can try:

```
@html_str.html_safe.lstrip
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub` for that

```
@html_str = "<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Remove whitespace</p>"
@html_str = @html_str.gsub("&nbsp;", "")
@html_safe_str = @html_str.html_safe
```

**or**

If you completely want to remove tags then as Andrey suggested, you can use strip_tags, but to use it in controller you need to call using `ActionController::Base`

```
@html_str = ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags("<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Remove whitespace</p>").gsub("&nbsp;", "").lstrip
```

It will output : `Remove whitespace`

Hope this helps!

Comment: you don't have to call `strip_tags` as you've shown. it simply works with `strip_tags(string)`. Comments in apidocs could be outdated ;)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko We cannot directly call `strip_tags` method in the controller I guess!

Comment: why would you ever need a string manipulation in controller? :)

Comment: That's correct, but in this question he wants to do string manipulation in the controller

Comment: I dont want to remove all the '&nbsp;" in the string. I want to remove all the &nbsp; immediately after the opening <p> tag.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(@html_str.html_safe).gsub("&nbsp;","").lstrip
# => "Remove whitespace"
```